# gunzip command not woriking for unzipping the file

Tags: zip

I am trying to unzip a file and I am getting below error. am using gunzip -c filename command.

gunzip: DEX_DWH.zip: first entry not deflated or stored -- use unzip

Adding points :
1. I don't want to use unzip command . I want gunzip -c command to unzip the file.
2. This is how my code is defined

elif [[ ! "${FILECOMMAND}" ]] && [[ -f "${ZIPFILE}" || -f "${ZIPFILE3}" || -f "${ZIPFILE2}" || -f "${ZIPFILE4}" ]]
then
  COMMANDTOUSE="gunzip -c"

FILECOMMAND - find the type of file and if its empty, gunzip -c comes into place.

Comment: The answer is right there in your question: `use unzip`

Comment: You wrote "I don't want to use unzip command", but that is the core of your problem. `gunzip` can only unpack `*.zip` files that contain a single file and are either compressed using the deflate algorithm or not compressed at all ("stored"). Both methods are normally not used by `zip`, so you have to use `unzip` with most `*.zip` files.

Answer (score 1):

According to the file name, your file is a `zip` archive. For that, you need to use the `unzip` tool:

```
unzip DEX_DWH.zip -d DEX_DWH
```

This extracts the files into a new directory `DEX_DWH`. If you want to extract the files into the working directory instead, you do not need the `-d DEX_DWH` part.

The `gzip` utility is intended for working with `gzip`-compressed files (ie. not archives, for that you normally use `tar` before compressing/after decompressing).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file` command to determine the file type to understand what tool you need to use to extract your archive.